# Alerts/Notifications on Meteor application do not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I created a new "Alerts" collection. Its to show number of unread messages. Messages get submitted and appear, and theres no other error on console or server.

2nd issue is, when i click on the specific room, it is supposed to mark all new messages as "read". Somehow the number stays. Error shows `Exception in queued task: .added@http://localhost:3000/app/lib/collections/messages.js`

**File structure:**

- roomList.js - shows a list of all rooms, shows number of unread messages
- roomDetail.js - when click specific room in list, will mark message as
  "read", unread number dissapears.
- alerts.js (Alerts collection)
- messages.js (Messages collection)
- rooms.js (Rooms collection)

**publications and sub js**

```
Meteor.publish('alerts', function() {
    return Alerts.find({ userId: this.userId, read: false });
});
Meteor.subscribe('alerts')
```

**Alerts collection js**

```
Alerts = new Mongo.Collection('alerts');
Alerts.allow({
   update: ownsDocument,

   //if removed, shows error: 
   // insert failed: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'insert'.
   insert: function(){  
      return true;
   }
});

createMessageAlert = function(message) {
  if ( message.user !== Meteor.userId() ){     
      Alerts.insert({
         userId        : message.user,
         roomId        : Router.current().params._id, //params id of current room
         messageId     : message._id,
         read          : false
      });
   }
};
```

**roomDetail.js**

```
  Messages.insert({          
     roomId    : Router.current().params._id,
     msg       : message,
     user      : Meteor.user()._id
  });
  template.find('input').value = '';
  createMessageAlert(message);
```

**roomsList.js**

```
Template.list.helpers({
   alerts: function (){
      return Alerts.find({ userId: Meteor.userId(), read: false });
   },
   alertCount: function(){
      return Alerts.find({ userId: Meteor.userId(), read: false }).count();
   }
});

Template.allRooms.events({
   'click a': function() {     //click the a href to go into roomDetail
      Alerts.update(this._id, {$set: {read: true}});
   }
});
```

Comment: Did you check if alert is added to db?

Comment: I mean via mongo shell or with some kind of mongo client tool

Comment: @Areca Mongol shows nothing. Ive updated the console statements which also shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**Ultimate solution :**

You should call the **createMessageAlert** from a trigger when a new Message is added in **Messages** collection.

**Pre-requisites:**

1. create a trigger(MSG_OBSERVER) for Messages collection, where whenever anything is added to the collection, a **createMessageAlert** method is invoked provided with the added document object, so you can play inside the method and do desired operations.
2. When you are updating **Alerts** collection. The collection should be published in such a way(named as "null") that it should be reactive and should be available from all the instances accessing the same account from different browser instances.

**Implementation**

Just add below code in your collections.js

```
Meteor.method(
'createMessageAlert': function(id, fields) {
      if ( fields.user !== Meteor.userId() ){ 
          Alerts.insert({
             userId        : fields.user,
             roomId        : Router.current().params._id, //params id of current room
             messageId     : id,
             read          : false
          });
       }
    }
);

var MSG_OBSERVER = Messages.find();

MSG_OBSERVER.observe({
  added: function(id, fields){
        Meteor.call('createMessageAlert', id, fields);
  }
});

Meteor.publish(null ,function() { // null name means send to all clients
        //use Messages.insert() to generate a fake message and add data in below params
        Meteor.call('createMessageAlert', id, fields);
        return Alerts.find();
});
```

**Explaination**

1. If you again read the pre-requisites, you will understand the code. Ensure you are subscribed with desired collection on client side. This code makes every collection involved and triggers very reactive and responsive.
2. Whatever you will add as messages will be added to Alerts as well.
3. Publishing "null" will simply publish data to all clients making UI behavior more robust and asynchronous.(I am using this feature in displaying real-time graphs, you don't even have to refresh UI  and your data gets reflected.)
4. While publishing "null", you can create a fake Message OBJ and add it to call **createMessageAlert** function. You have to do this because you have to initiate publish on server restarts. choose Message Obj wisely so that it won't impact the work flow.

Comment: There is no such null subscription, publishing null is like broadcasting all clients, you are publishing 'null' to broadcast Alerts.find(), so all clients will be updated. You can write that code in messages collection. You have to publish all three viz., Alerts, Messages and Null. You can remove the createmessagealert method from 'null' publish.

Comment: Thanks! for [1] you can write a Meteor.methods({ 'createMessageAlert' : function(id, fields) {}}); and then call it using Meteor.call( 'createMessageAlert', id, fields); You should write this code in SERVER. For [2] I don't know your code, you will have to post some code where the problem persist. So, that I can help you.

Comment: now it throws this error here: `MSG_OBSERVER.observe({
   added: function(id, fields){
      createMessageAlert(id, fields);
  }
});` says `createMessageAlert` is not defined. I will update on the various file structures. Im quite confused on what should go where

Comment: I think in roomDetails.js, when you are calling createMessageAlert, you should assign read :true. As you have entered the room, The room details js is called. I dont see any code where you have assigned read : true.

Comment: post the code where the "Read" fields is set to true. There must be some code where, when you enter the Room, you must have set the flag to true.

Comment: you will have to use Alerts.update({your_field:this._id}, {$set: {read: true}});

Comment: I changed `fields' to 'messages` and left `id` as it is in Meteor Method. Similarly I changed the same for publish and observe codes. Secondly, I removed the meteor call line from publish. Im getting error: `cannot read property user of undefined` in `messages.user` in the Meteor method line `if ( messages.user !== Meteor.userId() ){ `