# Calling HTTP method when something in DB changes, Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, oracle, meteor

I am stuck at this. I have an OracleDB where there is a table with some locations. I am calling an HTTP method via RESTful webservice to get my data. Now I want to make this smooth and use this method to get my data on the server only when something in OracleDB changes. I call it something like this:

```
HTTP.call("GET", "my_url", {data: "json"}, function (error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Webservice success - data");
    // parseJson(result);
  }
});
```

This is the server code. I put data in a collection and then use it on the client. I want to achieve that this method is called only when something changes in DB. I checked Tracker.autorun function which can help me with this I think. But how can I achieve this is going to be called once on the server and not everytime? (something like bodyOnLoad function but on the server). If I am missing something really obvious please give me a link where I can read the life cycle, because I can't really find a proper one.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [this article](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-01-05-websockets-vs-rest-api-understanding-the-difference/)

> REST organizes these Requests in predictable ways, using HTTP operation types, or verbs, to contruct appropriate responses. Requests originate from the client, and the common HTTP verbs include GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

And consider using a WebSocket for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely refer above link to understand the requirement for REAL_TIME application. what you want is real time solution, where, user just connects to server only once and never asks for data, instead data is automatically provided when demanded.

You may also like to [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205248/alerts-notifications-on-meteor-application-do-not-appear/37210938#37210938)

Above link gives you information on how to establish a robust and responsive relation between client and server.